# Unable to Open Model Popup using ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have this code and I am trying to open a Model Popup

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit ", "My_Action", "My_Controller", new { Tag_List = Item._tags }, new { @class = "btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-tags", @data_target = "#tagsmodal" })
<div id="tagsmodal" class="modal fade">
</div>
```

But when I click on it, it opens the PartialView in new page, instead of Model Popup

What am I doing wrong here

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because your code turns into following HTML (this html is send to the user):

```
<a href="/My_Controller/My_Action" class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-tags">Edit</a>
<div id="tagsmodal" class="modal fade">
</div>
```

This means that the a opens a new page if there is **no javascript** doing something else.

Razor C# code has **no influence** on what happens in the page. in the browser/page it is only html&javascript(&css) Razor&C# means nothing and wont be send to the client/browser and thus do not do anything. (it only generates this html and javascript which then is send to to browser).

In the browser you can view source:
[image]

to see what HTML was generated by razor. you will need to write javascript (an AJAX call) to make this url/data page open in a modal instead of a new page.